# Cannot SSH connect to Bitnami WordPress

Tags: wordpress, ssh, bitnami

we broke something in our lightsail instance and it does not work anymore. The website is down, and we cannot connect to the server through VCN or SSH.

What did we do before all of this happened?
We tried to install a wp plugin, it failed because of permission issues. Then we connected to the server thought ssh and try to change the permission of wp-content. It seemed the bitnami users did not have access to the folder of this file. Then we try a couple of comands.
The last one was a chmod 644 ....

After this, the website was down and we were not able to connect to the instance anymore.

When we try to connect to VCN, there is no error, but nothing appears in the console. And when we try to connect thought SSH we get this error:

```
ssh -v -i path_to_key bitnami@publicIP
```

```
debug1: Trying private key: ./valeraSalazones.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
bitnami@15.188.142.24: Permission denied (publickey).
```

What have we tried to solve this?
1- Restart the AWS lightsail instance --- It did not do anything
2- Create a snapshot and replicate it in other instance --- Same output
3- Create new key ---- Nothing change
4- Create an EC2 instance from the snapshot --- Nah, the same

We are kind of desperate on this matter. Hopefully, we can recover the WordPress site somehow.

NEW INFORMATION:
Following this [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/replacing-lost-key-pair.html#step-5-detach-root-volume-and-attach-to-temp-instance), I got to mount the volume on an EC2 machine and access to the content.

Now, I need to prepare to use this EBS to create a new instance and configure it all in an EC2 instance, because lighsail does not have any way for recovering this information.

Does anyone know how to proceed?

Should I launch an amit with the bitnami wordpress and manually replace the volumne?

Comment: Have you tried to mount the lightsail instance's snapshot to an existing EC2 instance? and since you have created a new key pair [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/replacing-lost-key-pair.html) document might help you as well.

Comment: Hi @AchyutVyas, yes we tried that, but even with the new key, we cannot access to the instance. I am going to repeat the whole process again just in case.

Comment: I mean you have to add the snapshot to the already created EC2 instance and change the public key inside the **authorized_keys** folder. (So you have two volumes in an EC2 instance, first one is primary instance volume and the second one is a snapshot of lightsail)

Comment: @AchyutVyas, I got to mount the EBS to a new instance and access the content. Thanks!